# How can I make a local docker container?

Tags: docker, containers

I installed Docker and kitematic. I had VirtualBox before that and used many machines on Vbox. Docker is working, I can pull containers and other stuff like that. Like this link : https://docs.docker.com/mac/started/
I can add containers by:

```
<i> docker run docker/whalesay cowsay boo </i>
```

I want to know if there is any way that I can import some of my Vbox machines into docker as a Container locally?
I have ova and ovf file in my local pc. I don't wanna get involved with online containers! Is there any way to accomplish this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have some confusion on the concept of a container.

**A container is not a virtual machine**.

You can't import virtual machines into Docker. What you can do is build and run a Docker container which eliminates the need for a virtual machine (depending on your use case of course).

You can find a good explanation about the difference between a container and a virtual machine [here](https://www.docker.com/what-docker).

**TL;DR**:

Both virtual machines and containers allow you to run multiple applications on a shared hardware.

When using **virtual machines**, the hardware is shared among all applications, however each application runs on a separate **operating system**.

When using **containers**, both the **hardware** AND the **operating system** are shared, and each application runs in a separate **container**.

This is in no way an exhaustive explanation regarding Docker containers - there are MANY more advantages to using Docker instead of a virtual machine (portability, consistency, infrastructure-as-code). This is just the main difference between them.

Comment: i just wanna have a apache server as a container on a windows 10 . but locally and nothing need to connect to internet . then let programmers add and test their codes on it .

Comment: You can find instructions on doing it here: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/ However, you must have internet connectivity initially in order for Docker to be able to download the relevant images, unless you use a private Docker registry locally (which you probably don't).